# Oracle : can i specify * or any other option in WHERE clause to select whatever value it has?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to database.

I am dynamically creating oracle queries in my code. if the columns have value then i have no problem. If columns have "null" values then the problem comes.

For example if I have to select a column with NULL values in oracle,

```
select * 
from <table> 
where "column_name" is NULL;
```

but I don't want to use is NULL, because I am generating queries dynamically and the format of the query is

```
select * 
from <table> 
where "column_name" = NULL;
```

but this doesn't work. So in place of NULL, can I write something that it automatically select a column with NULL option or anything like "*" to select any value in that column?

Comment: Perhaps you should declare your column to be `NOT NULL` and give it a default value.

Comment: Since you are dynamically generating why cant you remove the `WHERE` clause altogether when you don't need any filter

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `NVL` :

```
select * from <table> where NVL("column_name",-99) = -99;
```

Comment: what if the `column` is varchar datatype. Also I think he is asking the different thing( because of words " dynamically" ,"column(s)"  ).

Comment: What if the column is a varchar? what would be the problem? @sql_dummy

Comment: the attributes should be of same datatype, or comptible for conversion I guess

Comment: That doesn't matter what datatype the column is, `NVL` checks if it null, if it is it replace it with -99, and compare it to -99. @sql_dummy

Comment: also i think the question is actually something like this "In a row if any column has a null value, select that row" (as far as i understood)

Comment: And thats exactly what this query is doing(only on one column because he didn't specify any other)